# Not getting correct data from search function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I wrote my search function in the state of my component I got the results I expected. For example, I queried the google books api and I made a search for Halo. I got what I expect like Halo: Fall of Reach, Halo: The Flood ... etc.

But when I moved the search function into Redux, no matter what I search I get the same incorrect data returned. How does this happen?

So this is my action in redux

```
export const searchedBooks = search => async dispatch => {
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${search}&orderBy=relevance&maxResults=30&key=API_KEY`;

  try {
    const res = await axios.get(url, {
      transformRequest: [
        (data, headers) => {
          delete headers["access-token"];
          delete headers["uid"];
          delete headers["client"];
          delete headers["expiry"];
          delete headers["token-type"];
          delete headers.common;
          return data;
        }
      ]
    });
    dispatch({
      type: SEARCH_BOOKS,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: error.response.data
    });
  }
};
```

Before I put this in my actions I tested it in React. It's pretty much the same code I used. I believe the error is coming from ${search} I don't know if template literals work the same in Redux.

Component where I do my search

```
class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    search: "",
    books: []
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }
  }

  searchBooks = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.searchedBooks();
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.books);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>hi from search</h1>
        <form>
          <input
            onChange={this.onChange}
            type="text"
            name="search"
            placeholder="Title or Author(s)"
            value={this.state.search}
          />
          <button onClick={this.searchBooks}>Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  books: state.books
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { searchedBooks }
)(Search);
```

Comment: In what way is the returned data incorrect?

Comment: I get the same data returned regardless of what I search.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Network tab in Chrome dev tools? Can you view the Request URL? Should be able to see if it's being formatted properly.

Comment: Ah, where `${search}` is it says `undefined` now. I had a feeling it was the url request in the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually passing a parameter to `this.props.searchedBooks`.  Presumably you want the value from your input, so just update `searchBooks` to:

```
searchBooks = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.searchedBooks(this.state.search);
};
```